# How to delete a item in Expense Tracker in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an Expense Tracker app in React and I want to delete the items that I add but I can't. How can I write function for deleting items?

```
const[list,setList] = useState([]);   
    const[typeSelectedValue,setTypeSelectedValue] = useState("income");
    const [amount,setAmount] = useState();
    const [ category,setCategory] = useState()
    const [ date,setDate] = useState()
const deleteHandler = ()=>{
       
   }
return(
{list.map((data,id)=>
    
       <div className='list-item'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={data.type==='income'?faAdd:faMinus}/>
      <span className='amount'>${data.amount}</span> 
     <span className='category'>{data.category}</span> 
       <span className='date'>{data.date}</span>
       <button className='trash' onClick={deleteHandler}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/></button></div>)}

)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter if you want to delete one element

```js
const deleteHandler = (deleteKey)=>{
  setList(list.filter(el=>el!==deleteKey))
}
```